# Why is it necessary to reassign the variable containing the setInterval in order for the counting function to work?

Tags: javascript

I was working on a function that began counting once the DOM loaded. When I click the pause button it stops, and when I click the resume button it continues to count. I am wondering, why is it necessary for me to reassign the `interval` to `null` in order for this to work. Isn't it already being reassigned once I click the `pause.addEventListener` and it hits the `start()` function?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let interval

  function increaseInterval() {
    counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
  }

  function start() {
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(function(){increaseInterval()}, 1000)
    }
  }

  function stop() {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      interval = null
    }
  }

  start()


  pause.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (pause.innerText == "pause") {
      stop();
      pause.innerText  = "resume";
    } else {
      start();
      pause.innerText = "pause";
    }
  })


})
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle here where we can reproduce your problem? It's not clear for me why you have to set interval to null. what doesn't work when you leave this out (btw you should also use `;` after clearinterval() function.

Comment: `start` and `stop` communicate between them using this variable. They "know" when to act according to the value that is assigned to it.

Comment: I give you this hint: `if (!interval)` means `if (interval != null)`

Comment: Hello , you can see your Interval variable using `console.log()` at start , when you just use clearInterval , i think it still remains defined and valued so it wont be equal to false , so your `if` condition won't come true and your statements wont be executed

Comment: don't link to something on github, you can create a fiddle right here on this page.

Comment: @cloned Why? I don't know how to create a fiddle on this page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because to create a new interval you do:

```
  function start() 
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(function(){increaseInterval()}, 1000)
    }
  }
```

When you call `clearInterval` your code stops the timer, but the variable `interval` keeps having a value and its value is not null, so when you do `if (!interval)` its result is false so it doesn't execute the `if` code.

When you set manually `interval = null`, then the result of `if (!interval)` is true so it creates a new interval.